# How to get all text from an xpath using lxml

Tags: python, html, lxml

I currently have the below

```
u = 'https://www.cruiseplum.com/search#{%22numPax%22:2,%22geo%22:%22US%22,%22portsMatchAll%22:true,%22numOptionsShown%22:100,%22ppdIncludesTaxTips%22:true,%22uiVersion%22:%22split%22,%22sortTableByField%22:%22dd%22,%22sortTableOrderDesc%22:false,%22filter%22:null}'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(u)
driver.maximize_window()

time.sleep(.3)

driver.find_element_by_id('restoreSettingsYesEncl').click() # select 'yes' on the webpage to restore settings
time.sleep(7) # wait until the website downloads data so we get a return value

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")
source_code = elem.get_attribute("innerHTML")

t = html.fromstring(source_code)    

for i in t.xpath('//td[@class="dc-table-column _2"]/text()'):
        print(i.strip())
```

The goal of this is to get the text from the webpage listed in the code. The problem I am running into, is if there are two ports listed in the "Route" column. The code I currently have will print it on 2 separate lines.

Here is an example html that I am having problems with:

```
<td class="dc-table-column _2">Fort Lauderdale <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> Venice</td>
```

For this example, it will print "Fort Lauderdale" on line 1, then "Venice" on line 2. I would like to be able to print them both on one line.

Comment: _For this example, it will print "Fort Lauderdale" on line 1, then "Venice" on line 2._ Isn't that happening because you're iterating over the elements and calling `print()`, which inserts a newline, on each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a consequence of your way of printing the results, as pointed out by [AMC in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60517562/how-to-get-all-text-from-an-xpath-using-lxml#comment107062576_60517562).

`print()` adds a newline to every string it prints.

**Alternative printing method**

```
results = t.xpath('//td[@class="dc-table-column _2"]/text()')

print(" ".join([r.strip() for r in results]))
```

**Output**

```
Barcelona Martinique Martinique Doha Doha Fort Lauderdale Venice Miami Miami Miami Miami [...]
```